# React Native : json.data is not a function. (In 'json.data()', 'json.data' is an instance of Array)]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I'm trying to display data from my web using API. My API is working correctly. But some how i face this issue `json.data is not a function. (In 'json.data()', 'json.data' is an instance of Array)]`. Can I anyone help me on this?

```
 _loadInitialState = async () => {

        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language_type');
        _onSetLanguage(myArray)

        var loadAll = this.props.navigation.getParam('loadAll');
        if (loadAll == true) { this.setState({ isLoading: true }) }

        var have_access = this.props.navigation.getParam('have_access');
        if (have_access != undefined) { this.setState({ have_access: have_access }) }
        if (staticData.get_centre_settings() != null) { this.setState({ have_access: true }) }

        let today = Moment();
        this.setState({
            today: Moment(today).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        })

        // alert(FetchURL.get_baseURL() +  "leave?centre_id=" + staticData.get_centre_settings().centre.centre_id)
        // alert(token)
        // return
        fetch(FetchURL.get_baseURL() +  "leave?centre_id=" + staticData.get_centre_settings().centre.centre_id, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,

            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            // alert(json)
            if (json.error) {
                alert(json.error);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    staffLeave: json.data(),
                    isLoading: false
                });


            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            alert(err)
            // alert(strings.data_fail);
        })
    this.setState({ view_access: true })


    }
```

I kept searching for this but couldn't find an answer that will make this clear.

Thanks!

Comment: you only need `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the response after `response.json()` as `json`. If you want to store it to state, use `json.data` and not `json.data()`, just as you check for `json.error`.

Comment: Thank you. I change ``json.data()`` to ``json.data``.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the error `json.data is not a function. (In 'json.data()', 'json.data' is an instance of Array)]`

What this is telling you is that `json.data` is not a callable function. Therefore `json.data()` will not work. `json.data` is an array per the error message. You would access some part of that by: `json.data[0]` But you'd want to check the length of that array and understand the type (which Typescript helps solve).

Answer (score 0):

```
// alert(json)
            if (json.error) {
                alert(json.error);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    staffLeave: json.data(),
                    isLoading: false
                });


            }
```

**Replace with**

```
 if (json.error) {
                alert(json.error);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    staffLeave: json.data,
                    isLoading: false
                });
            }
```

**hopefully**, it's work.

Comment: Hi, the method you gave. Didn't pop up any error but my data didn't display in dashboard. @Asad

Comment: can you share your API response (data)?, then I'll properly guide you.

Comment: can can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735124/react-native-i-getting-raw-data-in-display-page you can see here .

Comment: the issue is in your API data because staff_name is coming incorrect from DB. First, check your API code